# Using trace in Typed Racket

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, typed-racket

I'm having difficulty getting the `trace` module set up when using Typed Racket - my attempt is the following in a REPL:

```
#lang typed/racket

(require/typed racket/trace
               [trace (Symbol * -> Void)])

(define (add-four [num : Number])
  (+ 4 num))

(trace add-four)

(add-four 3)
```

This is from following along the [trace](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/debugging.html) and [type annotation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/typed-untyped-interaction.html#%28part._.Using_.Untyped_.Code_from_.Typed_.Code%29) docs, but I'm getting the error `trace: bad syntax in: trace` in the `trace` type annotation when importing - not sure where I've gone wrong!

Comment: `trace` is a macro form, not a function. It doesn't have a value like one, you can't put a normal contract around it, and you can't put a normal type on it. There are certain macros that just don't work well in typed racket unless they are specially made for typed racket, and right now, sometimes the only way around it is to define new version of it

Comment: Ahh I see. Not sure if my macro chops are up to scratch but maybe I'll revisit this further down the line. I'll just make do without `trace` while I'm using typed racket for now. Thanks, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything that was a really simple fix - if you repost your comment as an answer, I'll accept it :)